# Bootstrap 3 - position modal on top of button when clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

It is easy to show a modal window when a button is clicked using twitter bootstrap. I am wondering if there is any way to display modal window on top of a button when clicked on it. In the below image, if i click on **pay now** button, see where the modal appears.

Is there any feasible way to achieve that ?

**Important thought:**

It should be responsive. That is the modal window should not get cut-off if viewed on mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/ for better mobile support. To open modal window on hover you can use the code in http://jsbin.com/weniyuto/1/

Comment: Although this is not what i was looking for but i liked it. I dont see any options to achieve what i want. Thanks. I am going to use this. Solved !

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Why would you say that this answer does nothing to resolve your question, then mark it "solved"?

Comment: I wanted the modal window to display like a popover. But i realized it will create problems in mobile devices. So i had to change my requirement.